# Why does it give warning when I run GStreamer application?

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I can compile the first gstreamer tutorial found [here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735).

However, when try to run it, I get a warning like this:

```
(basic-tutorial-1:27661): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.53: undefined symbol: lame_set_VBR_quality
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

How can I solve the `lame_set_VBR_quality` problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two unrelated problems reported in output:

### gstffmpeg

on startup, gstreamer scans for available plugins and tries to load them.
among these plugins is the file `/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so`.

it seems that you have installed incompatible libraries  (e.g. your gstreamer "ffmpeg" plugin depends on a different version of `libavcodec.so`), so the ffmpeg-plugin set cannot be loaded.

the problem is not really related to gstreamer itself, but rather to the way how you installed those libraries.

since linux-distributions usually are all about resolving inter-package dependencies (so that you can never install a package "foo-2.0" that depends on "bar-0.4" if you only have "bar-0.1" installed), i guess that you have added some non-official unsupported 3rd-party repositories (e.g. on debian, a common source of headaches is the *deb-multimedia* repository; other distros will have others).

if all libraries installed are from the official repository of your distro, chances are that you hit a bug in the packaging and you should report the bug to the maintainers of the package(s) providing the faulty libraries.

### jack

the other "error" about jack not being able to start, is because the pipeline you are using uses the generic `playbin2` element, which probes for available playback backends. while doing so, it also tries to connect to a running [jack](http://jackaudio.org)-server, fails to do so and (hopefully) falls back to another available audio framework.

Answer (score 1):

One additional comment on the audio side. Check whether something simple as gst-launch audiotestsrc ! autoaudiosink works. Try again with pulsesink or alsasink instead of autoaudiosink. These 2 would be tried before considering jack.