# reading videos in matlab not working (the following codec(s) to be installed on your system)

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg, codec, mpeg

When I try to read a video in matlab `v = VideoReader('t.avi');` I get this error:

```
The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system:
    video/x-msvideo
```

and some time it needs `mpeg` codec when I try to load mpeg or mp4 video.

I found someone referring to rename libstdc++.so.6.0 to libstdc++.so.6.0.10 but I found that I already have libstdc++.so.6.0.13

I'm using matlab 2013 with archlinux.

Update: I get this warring in the terminal when trying to read a video

```
Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstpango.so':
/usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Face_GetCharVariantIndex
```

Comment: Besides Matlab, can other video players which rely on external Codecs play the video?

Comment: if you mean running videos for example with vlc, yes all videos are working just fine, it's working with opencv+python.  I only got error with matlab

Comment: Vlc brings it's own Codecs which, but opencv to my knowledge not. So we know the Codecs exist on your system and can be used.

Comment: I think this answer could be relevant to my problem. but I don't know how to check if a certain package in broken. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782584/why-does-it-give-warning-when-i-run-gstreamer-application